# How to use AttributeSet in Android (needed to use MapView from Mapbox)

Tags: android, mapbox

I would like to put a Mabpox MapView in my android application. The MapView should get the tiles from the internet, not from a file. Therefore I created a mapbox account to get a mapbox id.

I am now stuck setting the mapbox id on the MapView, because the [mapbox quick-start guide](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/blob/mb-pages/QUICKSTART.md) seems to be out of date. The MapView constructor looks like this:

```
public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
```

I understand that the AttributeSet wants an attribute containing my mapbox id. Therefore I created a file called attrs.xml inside /res/values/ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MapView">
        <attr name="mapid" format="string">brgr.myId</attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

For testing purposes, I have created a new application module with a MainActivity, where I would simply set the MapView as the ContentView for now, for making things easier.

My problem now is that the Mapbox constructor needs an AttributeSet, but I don't know how to convert the attrs.xml file into an AttributeSet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    XmlPullParser parser=getResources().getXml(R.xml.attrs);
    AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
    mapView = new MapView(this, attrs);
```

Also, the `attrs.xml` file should be in `res/xml/`, not in `res/values/`.

Comment: When doing this, `xml` (in `R.xml.attrs`) is displayed red and when hovering over it, Android Studio tells me the following: `Cannot resolve symbol 'xml'`.

Comment: I've found the error: The file `attrs.xml` should be in `res/xml/` and not in `res/values/`. The app now compiles and starts fine. (However, the tiles are still not loaded. But I think for this I will open an issue at their github repository.) 

Thanks for your help!! :)